# Best tools to teach animations of solids of revolution in a Calculus II class?

Tags: calculus

I would like to show animations of solids of revolutions particularly to those students who are not visualizers. Is there a tool that I (and preferably my students also) can use to create animations? It would be great to know what you use in classroom and how successful it has been.

Answer (score 3):

Free software GeoGebra from [www.geogebra.org](http://www.geogebra.org) will let you do this. Here is an example
https://www.geogebra.org/m/mzWq2Cet and a video showing the construction of a solid of revolution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wOtyT86Qhw.
Your construction can easily be exported as html and embedded in a website too.

Answer (score 1):

[CalcPlot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html) has the ability to plot a surface of revolution, and it lets you animate the revolution, as well as display washers/shells for visualizing volumes.

[image]